# Can you tell which are the canon laser printers that suport in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: printing, canon

Can you give which are the canon laser printers that suport in ubuntu 12.04?

is Laser Shot LBP2900 support in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Please visit this page and see: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrintersCanon

Comment: http://support-in.canon-asia.com/contents/IN/EN/0900772424.html

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190

Answer (score 0):

[Install a Canon LBP2900 on Ubuntu 12.04, 32bits](http://une-terre.blogspot.fr/2012/12/install-canon-lbp2900-on-ubuntu-1204.html)
Some fight ahead, but that may work !